# How do I loop through dataGrid rows to check if a CheckBox is ticked or not in WPF

Tags: wpf

Im making a table in which i want to loop through to see if a checkBox is ticked orr not. all the rows that have ticked checkboxes, i want to add a few columns from into a list.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of problem is easily solved by separating the user interface from the data.

Make a data item class, including a boolean IsSelected property.

Set the ItemsSource of your datagrid to a collection of these data items. Bind the checkbox column of your datagrid to IsSelected.

You can now scan the data item collection, using Linq or otherwise, to find the selected items.

What I've described would be covered by the [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) design pattern, which is the recommended application structure for WPF development.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try